# error TS2339: Property 'e164Number' does not exist on type 'string'

Tags: angular, typescript

He integrado en mi aplicación **angular** ngx-intl-tel-input para recoger el numero de teléfono.

Mi problema es que cuando se rellena el formulario, en el campo de phone_number me recoge un objeto con varios campos:

```
phone_number: 
    countryCode: "ES"
    dialCode: "+34"
    e164Number: "+34671000000"
    internationalNumber: "+34 671 00 00 00"
    nationalNumber: "671 00 00 00"
    number: "671000000"
```

Yo necesito solo el dato: **e164Number** , el ultimo.

El problema es que no consigo acceder a ese dato. Y si intento acceder de este modo:

```
this.user.phone_number.number.e164Number
```

Me da un error:

> error TS2339: Property 'e164Number' does not exist on type 'string'.

¿Alguna idea?

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No puedes acceder a  `this.user.phone_number.number.e164Number` ya que si te fijas bien **`number`** y **`e164Number`** se encuentran en el mismo nivel, por lo tanto no puedes hacer **`...number.e164Number`**.

Estando ambos en el mismo nivel deberías hacer:

```
this.user.phone_number.e164Number
```

Y no así acceder a **`number`**.

Agregaré un ejemplo funcional de lo que sucede:

```js
const user = {
  phone_number: {
    countryCode: "ES",
    dialCode: "+34",
    e164Number: "+34671000000",
    internationalNumber: "+34 671 00 00 00",
    nationalNumber: "671 00 00 00",
    number: "671000000"
  }
};

// Hasta number obtenemos "671000000" que es solo un string
console.log(user.phone_number.number);

// En este caso el valor no existe porque como dijimos, es un string (problema que tienes)
console.log(user.phone_number.number.e164Number);

// Pero si podemos acceder directamente a la propiedad "e164Number" al igual que number
console.log(user.phone_number.e164Number);
```

Comment: Gracias Israel-ICM por contestar. Si, me di cuenta de ese error. De todos modos lo solucione por otra vía. No se si es muy ortodoxo pero me vale. Dentro de <ngx-intl-tel-input ..... > Añadí  (ngModelChange)="user.phone_number = $event?.e164Number" . Esto hace que me guarde el valor tal y como lo necesito. Asi me ahorro tener que crear un array en el TS para luego extraer la información. Muchas gracias por tu respuesta